# A way of understanding the $dx$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In an attempt to explain the concept of the infinitesimal change, I have defined it as such :
Given an interval of size $L$, we could express $L$ as follows :$L=\alpha.dx$ thus, theoretically, $\alpha = \frac{L}{dx}$ could be seen as the total number of $x$s since $dx$ is infinitesimally small.
Do you think this to be a conceptually wrong explanation?

Comment: What is the official definition of differential you are referring to?

Comment: not really referring to anything, i'm just looking to know whether i got it right or wrong if i try explaining it this way

Comment: Since you are talking about "a personal definition of the differential" you should clarify what is the other not personal definition of the differential you are reffering to, what is the context, otherwise your claim is really unclear.

Comment: Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(mathematics)

Comment: and to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function

Comment: and to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio/21209#21209

Comment: edited the title. just wanted to know that my understanding of if you divide a an interval of length L into a bunch of dxs then the total number of xs could be seen as n = L/dx

Comment: [Here is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2519686/difference-between-differentiation-and-derivatives/2519758#2519758) a short description of the difference between *derrivative* and *differentiable*.

Comment: The initial statement: "Given an interval of size $L$, we could express $L$ as follows :$L=\alpha.dx$" is completely unclear and it seems to be not true. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean that if you have, for example, a rope of length $L$ and you divide it into bits of size $dx$ then you could express its length as follows $L = \alpha . dx$ i.e $L = dx + dx + dx + ...$

Comment: The number of $x$s cannot be invoked, that is meaningless. Furthermore, introducing two "variables" $L$ and $\alpha$ gives no insight in what a differential is.

Comment: I meant $dx$ by differential, the infinitesimal change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider the interval of length $L$ divided in $n$ equal parts of length $\Delta x$ therefore we have

$$\Delta x= \frac L n \iff L=n\cdot \Delta x$$

we can then define the infinitesimal interval as

$$dx:=\lim_{n\to \infty }\Delta x= \lim_{n\to \infty }\frac L n= \frac L {\lim_{n\to \infty }n}=0$$

but it is meaningless write $$dx=\frac L \infty$$

since $\infty$ is not a number

Comment: let it as a variable that is by definition the total number of $x$s and you could work out with it the average value of a function for example : $\sum \frac{f(x)}{n} = \frac{1}{L} \sum f(x).dx = \frac{1}{L} \int f(x).dx$

Comment: This the concept of Riemann sum, take a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/750953/505767

Answer (score 0):

In concrete terms, an infinitesimal change is *so small that the linear approximation holds*.

The local behavior of a smooth function can be described as

$$f(x+h)=f(x)+ah+r(x,h)$$

where $a$ is a constant and $r$ a remainder term that vanishes when $h$ tends to zero, $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{r(x,h)}h=0$.

Then $h$ infinitesimal means that we can just drop the remainder term and "admit" the equality

$$f(x+h)=f(x)+ah.$$

Comment: In the last maybe you should use $\approx$?

Comment: @gimusi: precisely not. When $h$ is infinitesimal, the equality holds exactly, *by convention* (this is another way to say that we replace the function by its differential).

Comment: Ah ok, I'm not used to this notation, I write $f(x+h)=f(x)+ah+o(h)$ and (for $f$ not linear) $f(x+h)\approx f(x)+ah$ and $l(x+h)=f(x)+ah$ as a linear approximation of $f(x)$ at $x$.

Comment: I mean it seems a little confusing use the same symbol f to indicate the function and its linear approximation. But it is a detail of course.

Comment: @gimusi: it is non-official. But I have subsituted approximation with equality.

Comment: Indeed as you noted I’m not claiming that it is official, I’ve only claimed that your notation is a little bit confusing at a first sight because I’ m not used to it. After your explanation now it’s clear what it stands for.

Comment: Yes equality is then the appropriate term in that context.